# How to access key values from .yml file in a .js file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have an application.yml file with keys like:

```
key1: "foo1"
key2: "foo2"
key3: "foo3" etc...
```

I want to access, say, key3 in my .js file and interpolate it into a string.

The code I am working with in my js file is just this one line:

```
    'redirect_uri': `https://sample/file/path`
```

I want to replace "sample" with "key3" from my .yml file. so that it reads:

```
'redirect_uri': `https://foo3/foo5/foo6`
```

Ive tried to just interpolate the key as:

```
'redirect_uri': `https://${this.key3}/foo5/foo6`
```

but this has obviosuly not worked.

Comment: You can put YAML data as JSON inside your page. It's far from clear what the intent is here with path vs. properties and function calls(?).

Comment: The oriignal path that was set equal to redirect_uri had "staging" hardcoded into it. What I am trying to do is replace the word "staging" in my .js file with the new key created in the yml file.